# App crash - My android app

Tags: java, android, listview

I programmed my app to be using listview and I create my addapter class to extend ArrayAddapter and also I create my getter class to get my words into the view I want to inflate but when I run the app it stops.

my addapter class code

```
package charpman.com.quakereport;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by DCharpMan on 4/19/2017.
 * <p>
 * class to populate each list view item
 */

public class QuakeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<earthquakeClass> {


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context         The current context.
     * @param earthquakeClass the array to be populated
     */
    public QuakeAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<earthquakeClass> earthquakeClass) {
        super(context, R.layout.description_house, earthquakeClass);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View Customize = convertView;
        if (Customize == null) {
            Customize = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.description_house, parent, false);
        }
        earthquakeClass earthquakeClass = getItem(position);

        TextView textView = (TextView) Customize.findViewById(R.id.text_magnitude);
        textView.setText(earthquakeClass.getMagnitude());
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE, 2 + 1);


        TextView textView1 = (TextView) Customize.findViewById(R.id.text_loctaion);
        textView1.setText(earthquakeClass.getLocation());
        textView1.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, 1);

        TextView textView2 = (TextView) Customize.findViewById(R.id.text_daye);
        textView2.setText(earthquakeClass.getDate());
        textView2.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD, 3);


        return Customize;

    }

}
```

my mainActivity.java code

```
package charpman.com.quakereport;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final ArrayList<earthquakeClass> country = new ArrayList<earthquakeClass>();

        country.add(new earthquakeClass("7.2", "nigeria", "23,07,2017"));
        country.add(new earthquakeClass("7.2", "nigeria", "23,07,2017"));
        country.add(new earthquakeClass("7.2", "nigeria", "23,07,2017"));
        country.add(new earthquakeClass("7.2", "nigeria", "23,07,2017"));
        country.add(new earthquakeClass("7.2", "nigeria", "23,07,2017"));


        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        QuakeAdapter quakeAdapter = new QuakeAdapter(this, country);


        listView.setAdapter(quakeAdapter);

    }
}
```

my getter class code

```
package charpman.com.quakereport;

/**
 * Created by CharpMan on 4/19/2017.
 * class to get the earthQuake details
 * details includes Magnitude,location and date of earthquake
 */

public class earthquakeClass {

    // globale variables that holds the earthquake information
    String magnitude;
    String location;
    String date;

    //contructor for the class takes in three params
    // @param Magnitude tell the magnitude of the quake
    // @params Location tells the location where the quake occured
    // @params date tells the day of the quake
    public  earthquakeClass(String Magnitude, String Location, String Date){
        magnitude = Magnitude;
        location = Location;
        date = Date;

    }

    // create public methods that returns each information

    // method to the the magnitude
    public  String getMagnitude(){
        return magnitude;
    }

    // methid to return the loctaion
    public  String getLocation(){
        return  location;
    }

    // methid to return the day of quake occurence

    public String getDate (){
        return date;
    }



}
```

My MainActivity.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="charpman.com.quakereport.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Magnitude"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Location"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="date"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
      android:background="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>



</LinearLayout>
```

xml code for the Layout I inflate in my Addapter class's GetView method

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_magnitude"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="14dp"
            android:text="7.8" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_loctaion"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Nigeria"
            android:typeface="serif" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_daye"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:text="28,02,2017" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I include a screenshot of my logcat[image]

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: post your xml as well

Comment: post your Java methods and XML files for reference!

Comment: As per error log there is something wrong with your XML layout at line #46. Try correcting it or post the xml code.

Comment: Post code and logcats **as text**, not as screenshots!

Comment: i am so sorry if my question wasnt posted in a good way! it is just that i dont know how to postjava code and xml  code on stakoverflow.com , wish someone could help me on how to post code thanks

Comment: @Rotwang please help me i dont know how to do that. thanks

Comment: Select your code... Copy... come back here... paste it... Select your code and hit Ctrl++ (Ctrl and + hit together).

Comment: Same with your logcat.

Comment: `android:background="@android:color/secondary_text_light"` define/copy this color code in project `colors.xml` and use it.

Comment: @skadoosh thansk for the notice i appreciate my app works very fine now. God bless

Comment: @Rotwang thanks for your help! i learnt something I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to read through the Code and i notice that ion my ListView code I added a backgroud tag

android:background="@android:color/secondary_text_light"

I ought to have define/copy the color code in project colors.xml and use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the error log i think in your XML file there is something which is not compatible as per your adapter or maybe you are using an object in your adapter which is not present in your XML file.